# Flutter Charts using FutureBuilder with labelAccessorFn

Tags: flutter, charts

I am using a StreamBuilder to feed data for a [Flutter Charts outside label pie chart](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/outside_label) creation. A data field(*categoryId*), which is a integer foreign key from another data model, is being used as the domain and aggregated values(*expenseTotal*) is the measure. I am trying to use a FutureBuilder, which looks up from sqlite, to replace this data field with its respective descriptive string title with the labelAccessorFn. The future function(*getCategoryTitle*) is invokded correctely and correct title values retrieved, however, it never returns a ConnectionState.done for whatever reason. All that I am getting is a FutureBuilder.

I have success using FutureBuilder elsewhere, not in this case. I am hoping for some pointers. Thank you very much!

```
List<charts.Series<TotalByCategory, int>>
totalByCategorySeries = [
  charts.Series<TotalByCategory, int>(
  id: 'expenseByCategory',
  seriesColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Theme.of(context).accentColor),
  domainFn: (TotalByCategory expense, _) => expense.categoryId,
  measureFn: (TotalByCategory expense, _) => expense.expenseTotal,
  data: weeklyTotalByCategoryList,
  labelAccessorFn: (TotalByCategory row, _) => FutureBuilder<String> (
    future: getCategoryTitle(row.categoryId),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot categoryInfoSnapshot) {
      if (categoryInfoSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
        if(categoryInfoSnapshot.hasData) { return Text('${categoryInfoSnapshot.data.toString()}'); }
        return Text('?');
      }
      return Text('?');
    },).toString(),
  colorFn: (_, index) => charts.MaterialPalette.green.makeShades(weeklyTotalByCategoryList.length)[index],)];
```

Comment: `labelAccessorFn` should return a `String` but you are returning a `Widget` (`FutureBuilder`). (And, no, adding `toString` at the end doesn't count.) You need to move your `FutureBuilder` up, outside of the creation of the `Series`. Once you have your snapshot, you need to have all the data immediately available to create the `Series` - nothing `async` is allowed.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHeap. Your suggestion is what I was contemplating. I was just a little reluctant :)